# @hapi/boom not returning correct error, instead "500 : Internal Server Error"

Tags: node.js, error-handling, google-authentication, hapi, google-auth-library-nodejs

@hapi/boom is not returning correct error as thrown in code.
Here is the code sample:

controller.ts

```
async (request: IRequest, h: IResponse) => {
.... // some logic
   const userInfo = await verify(email, authToken)
   if (!userInfo) throw Boom.unauthorized(`Unable to fetch user information`)
.... some logic
   return h.response({ statusCode: 200, message: "Success", data })
} catch (error) {
   throw error
}
```

verify.ts

```
export async function verify(userEmail: string, token: string) {
   try {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
       idToken: token,
       audience: clientId
    })
    const payload = ticket.getPayload()
    if (!payload) throw Boom.unauthorized("Google authentication failed")
    const { sub: userId, name, email, aud, picture: profilePhoto } = payload
    if (!aud || aud !== clientId) throw Boom.unauthorized(`Invalid token for ${config.get("appName")}`)
    if (!email || email !== userEmail) throw Boom.unauthorized(`Invalid token for email ${userEmail}`)
    return { userId, name, profilePhoto, email }
 } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error)
    throw error
 }
}
```

Now, on error, it should either return **Unauthorized**, but it is returning **Internal Server Error** always.

Any solution to return actual error with information?

stack:

@hapi/hapi : 20.0.3

@hapi/boom : 9.1.1

Comment: Error 500 literally means that there's an error in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it won't help you anymore, since the question is 9 months old, but in the code you posted `clientId` is `undefined` in the `try` block. This means you end up in the `catch` block and (re)`throw` the original error.

Since you are using a regular `throw` in the `catch` block, hapi calls `throw Boom.internal()`, which is a HTTP 500 internal server error.